# How to create new array using get n value from first array and other from both first and second

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two different arrays, `setOne` and `setTwo`. I want to create a new array with 10 elements, but the first 3 elements should be randomly from first array (`setOne`), and the remaining 7 will be from both `setOne` and `setTwo`.

Here is the array:

```js
var setOne       = [['12+16','28'], ['15+11','26'], ['16+22','38'], ['13+14','27'], ['15+24','39'], ['14+12','26'], ['10+17','27'], ['11+11','22'],
                    ['13+15','28'], ['12+21','33'], ['24+13','37'], ['33+21','54'], ['40+18','58'], ['34+31','65'], ['25+42','67'], ['22+15','37'],
                    ['24+12','36'], ['20+15','35'], ['25+14','39'], ['21+21','42'], ['41+25','66'], ['53+24','77'], ['35+31','66'], ['62+37','99'],
                    ['54+35','89']];

var setTwo       = [['15+18=','33'], ['17+17=','34'], ['13+19=','32'], ['18+14=','32'], ['15+27=','42'], ['18+17=','35'], ['27+29=','56'], ['23+28=','51'],
                    ['36+37=','73'], ['45+25=','70'], ['46+45=','91'], ['38+57=','95'], ['49+43=','92'], ['37+53=','90'], ['48+33=','81']];
```

I tried below code-

```js
generateQues: function() {
         //Set position for set Questins
         //quesTextValue    = this.add.text(50,400,randQues[0], textStyleQues);
        // Generating random questions from given list of ques - setOne.
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {

        
           if(i<=3) {

                   var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * setOne.length);
                   //console.log(ranNum);
                 randQues = setOne[ranNum];

                    console.log(randQues);
               // quesTextValue    = this.add.text(50,400, randQues[0],textStyleQues);

            } else {
                var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * setTwo.length);
                var rque = setTwo[ranNum];
                console.log(rque);
                randQues.push(rque);
                console.log(randQues);


            }
        }
      
    // quesTextValue.destroy();
    },
```

Please help me for solve this problem.

Comment: did your code not work as expected , can you paste it here?

Comment: yes, i am editing question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some random values and splice the selected item to prevent duplicates in the result set.

```js
var setOne = [['12+16', '28'], ['15+11', '26'], ['16+22', '38'], ['13+14', '27'], ['15+24', '39'], ['14+12', '26'], ['10+17', '27'], ['11+11', '22'], ['13+15', '28'], ['12+21', '33'], ['24+13', '37'], ['33+21', '54'], ['40+18', '58'], ['34+31', '65'], ['25+42', '67'], ['22+15', '37'], ['24+12', '36'], ['20+15', '35'], ['25+14', '39'], ['21+21', '42'], ['41+25', '66'], ['53+24', '77'], ['35+31', '66'], ['62+37', '99'], ['54+35', '89']],
    setTwo = [['15+18=', '33'], ['17+17=', '34'], ['13+19=', '32'], ['18+14=', '32'], ['15+27=', '42'], ['18+17=', '35'], ['27+29=', '56'], ['23+28=', '51'], ['36+37=', '73'], ['45+25=', '70'], ['46+45=', '91'], ['38+57=', '95'], ['49+43=', '92'], ['37+53=', '90'], ['48+33=', '81']],
    sets = [setOne.slice(), setTwo.slice()],
    count = [3, 7],
    result = [],
    a, p;

while (count[0] + count[1]) {
    p = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (count[p]) {
        a = sets[p];
        result.push(a.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)[0], 1));
        count[p]--;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do like this; First three are unique random selections from the first array and the remaining seven are again unique random selections from a uninon of the two arrays.

```js
var setOne = [['12+16','28'], ['15+11','26'], ['16+22','38'], ['13+14','27'], ['15+24','39'], ['14+12','26'], ['10+17','27'], ['11+11','22'], ['13+15','28'], ['12+21','33'], ['24+13','37'], ['33+21','54'], ['40+18','58'], ['34+31','65'], ['25+42','67'], ['22+15','37'], ['24+12','36'], ['20+15','35'], ['25+14','39'], ['21+21','42'], ['41+25','66'], ['53+24','77'], ['35+31','66'], ['62+37','99'], ['54+35','89']],
    setTwo = [['15+18=','33'], ['17+17=','34'], ['13+19=','32'], ['18+14=','32'], ['15+27=','42'], ['18+17=','35'], ['27+29=','56'], ['23+28=','51'], ['36+37=','73'], ['45+25=','70'], ['46+45=','91'], ['38+57=','95'], ['49+43=','92'], ['37+53=','90'], ['48+33=','81']];
    s1Copy = setOne.slice(),
    result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) result.push(s1Copy.splice(~~(Math.random()*s1Copy.length),1)[0]);
s1Copy.push(...setTwo);
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) result.push(s1Copy.splice(~~(Math.random()*s1Copy.length),1)[0]);
console.log(result);
```